# Transpose in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, apache-toree

I am new to Scala. I am currently working on a jupyter notebook Apache Toree - Scala.
I have the following:

| dt_analysis | metric_name | mean_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-13 | FID | 337.07522229312184 |
| 2021-08-13 | CLS | 0.4778479558664849 |
| 2021-08-13 | LCP | 27853.39253624655 |
| 2021-08-14 | LCP | 1503.4752384264077 |
| 2021-08-14 | CLS | 0.4933521946102963 |
| 2021-08-14 | FID | 119.07927683323628 |
| 2021-08-15 | LCP | 1654.1969758061045 |

which is a "'void' class".

I wish to tranpose it and have metric_name as columns.
Note: there is one value per metric per dt_analysis.

Comment: What is a void class?

Comment: when I ran mydaf.getClass it gave me 'void'.

Comment: is this a DataFrame?

Comment: is this about Apache Spark?

Comment: @mfirry it is a void in Scala. Practically the output of an aggregation.

Comment: @Seth Tisue. My code is in Apache and the language is Scala.

Comment: Apache what? there are a ton of "Apache" things. is it Apache Spark specifically?

Comment: @seth Tisue, I am also mentioning it in the description. It is Apache Toree